# wordpress pagination fix after the_posts

Tags: pagination

I am using the_posts action to filter out some unwanted posts - this works fine, but the pagination after this is applied gets broken. If for example there is a page with 10 results before the_posts is applied, then after it gets applied the page displays only 6 posts for example, yet there is 100 posts in total and 20 of them should be excluded.

Pagination shows 1-10 pages when it should show 1-8.

So the question is - how to make pagination work as expected and display 10 posts per page and not to have pages with less than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `the_posts` filter, you should try [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action.

Comment: I managed to get things working using `pre_get_posts`. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of filtering posts inside the loop, you should try filtering them right after the loop. Query_posts() can solve the problem: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

This is how you can "merge" the modifications on the main query to insert any filters without messing the pagination:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score -2):

use this plugin

WP-Paginate is a simple and flexible pagination plugin which provides users with better navigation on your WordPress site

[wp-pagination](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/)